# How to test Framework if Unit tests are in separate assembly?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, integration-testing

I have assembly with my framework and assembly with tests. But I need to test internal classes or substitute some services.
For example,
- I need to test internal helper.
- My framework read and analyze files created by other application. I create these files manually for tests. But I can't give it to my framework from separate assembly. I need to create mock for internal service to provide these files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You want Your internal classes to be visible to your tests You must make your test assembly a friend of your framework assembly.

You have to add

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTestAssembly")]
```

in your framework assembly.

Here is a link to MSDN Documentation about friend assemblies - http://bit.ly/FriendAssemblies