# Exception "System.InvalidProgramException: JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation " has occured

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, jit

Sample code:

Below code is not complete but it is enough to show wt problem i am facing.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    class Class1
    {
         internal static void sum(ref List<TestClass> a, int b) 
         {

             //some code

         }
     }

}
```

There is another class in same assembly

```
namespace ClassLibrary1 
{
    class TestClass
    { 
         //code

    }

 }
```

when I create unit test case for method sum then code would be like

```
[TestMethod()] 
public void sumTest()
{
    List<TestClass_Accessor> lstTestClass = new List<TestClass_Accessor>(); 
    Class1_Accessor.sum(ref lstTestClass, b); 
}
```

Problem: In above code I am creating list of type TestClass but it is private class so VSTS create TestClass_Accessor to access class functionality. 
In method Sum, It takes parameter as a reference of list of type "TestClass".

I have also debug my code but when

`Class1_Accessor.sum(ref lstTestClass, b);` is debugged it throws exception "System.InvalidProgramException: JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation ".

When i created list of string type then it works i.e. list has no problem.

As per my understanding problem is in type of list. in unit test we create list of type `TestClass_Accessor`.

And in class list has type `List<TestClass>`.

please provide solution for this.

Regards,

Nitin Sahu

Answer (score 0):

I have problems understanding what You are saying. But...
TestClass is not private in code You provided. By default it is internal when no access modifier is specified. And You can easily access internal members in Your tests. Maybe You won't have any problems when You eliminate additional stuff (TestClass_Accessor).

Look here: [How to test Framework if Unit tests are in separate assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048495/how-to-test-framework-if-unit-tests-are-in-separate-assembly/6050615#6050615)

And BTW You don't need `ref` when passing reference values.

Comment: Sometimes, `ref` is needed even with reference values. For example when the type is immutable. But I'm not sure it's needed here.

Comment: Not sure what You mean with immutable types. You can pass reference type by ref when You want to change what reference points to after method call.

Comment: With mutable types, you can change the value in some way (e.g. changing the `Name` of a `Person`) without changing the reference, so you may not need `ref`. With immutable types (such as `string`), if you want the change to be apparent in the calling method, you always need `ref`.

Comment: As i mentioned at the top of query that code is not completed BTW let me tell you more clearly. Class1 is internal.There is Internal method "Sum" of class1. To create unit test for this meyhod, I need Accessor of class1 b/c it is internal.
Method sum take first parameter as a list of TestClass.So when I call method sum in my unit test case. I also need to create list of type TestClass_Accessor(B/c Test class is also internal)

Comment: Problem is I create List object of type TestClass_Accessor and in actual method has List object of type TestClass. You produce same scenario at your end. Create list object of user defined class type that should be internal. If you have any other doubt please let me know and provide any solution if you find.

Answer (score 0):

Using "ref" is part of the problem here. I had the same problem and it went away when not using the "ref" keyword.

As Peri already stated, using ref is not needed here.